# xQuery on returning maximum element

Tags: xml, xquery

I am relatively new to xQuery. And I have been struggling to get a working solution for this.
Basically i have the following xml:

```
<skills>
    <skill name="XQuery" level="2"/>,
    <skill name="R" level="1"/>,
    <skill name="Python" level="4"/>,
    <skill name="Python" level="5"/>,
    <skill name="Java" level="2"/>,
    <skill name="C" level="2"/>,
    <skill name="C" level="5"/>
</skills>
```

My expected result is:

```
<skill name="XQuery" level="2"/>,
<skill name="Python" level="5"/>,
<skill name="R" level="1"/>,
<skill name="Java" level="2"/>,
<skill name="C" level="5"/>
```

For all elements with the same name, I would like to return the maximum value.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it:

```
let $xml :=
  <skills>
    <skill name="XQuery" level="2"/>,
    <skill name="R" level="1"/>,
    <skill name="Python" level="4"/>,
    <skill name="Python" level="5"/>,
    <skill name="Java" level="2"/>,
    <skill name="C" level="2"/>,
    <skill name="C" level="5"/>
  </skills>

for $distinct-name in distinct-values($xml/skill/@name)
let $skills := $xml/skill[@name = $distinct-name]
let $max := max($skills/@level)
return $skills[@level = $max][1]
```

This is another solution (using XQuery 3.1):

```
let $xml :=
  <skills>
    <skill name="XQuery" level="2"/>,
    <skill name="R" level="1"/>,
    <skill name="Python" level="4"/>,
    <skill name="Python" level="5"/>,
    <skill name="Java" level="2"/>,
    <skill name="C" level="2"/>,
    <skill name="C" level="5"/>
  </skills>

for $skills in $xml/skill
group by $name := $skills/@name
return sort($skills, function($skill) { number($skill/@level) })[last()]
```

Comment: which of the two would you consider more efficient? Also what does function($skill) do for the second solution?

Comment: sort(...) will usually be faster, but this also depends on the XQuery implementation. For more information on the function, please check out the comprehensive specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-sort